# Navigate to content pages do not work on myasp.net hosting site

Tags: asp.net, hosting

I have published my website on myasp.net server, Everything is working correctly except any content page inside folder, when i navigate to any page inside folder i get blank white page, but pages in the root directory are working correctly , and when i copy any page form it's folder to the root directory it works fine 
example 
login page link(root directory page) is working
http://ammm199462-001-site1.gtempurl.com/About.aspx
username: ahmed
password: 123
when you login by this link you should go to about page and also this page work because it is on the root directory

Any page except this two pages are in folders so they do not work
example 
Products page link(in folder page) don't work
http://ammm199462-001-site1.gtempurl.com/Products/Products.aspx

but when i copy the last page (Products page) to the root directory it works
fine , and i have page that user redirect to it if an exception happen and it works fine with the page in the root directory
example : error in about page link
http://ammm199462-001-site1.gtempurl.com/Abo2ut.aspx

and when i copy the default.asp(first and only page be in the server when i ran it for first time) in a folder it works fine

may some links don't work with you because i have made a lot of changes in the hosted files and folders

the problem clearly, content pages that are inside folders are not work

Master page

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="ShopSystem.MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>System Name</title>


     <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
   <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="~/Images/PenguinWebSiteIcone.png" /> 
      <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../Images/PenguinWebSiteIcone.png" />

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
<%--    <link href="~/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" runat="server"/>--%>

        <link href="~/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" runat="server"/>
        <link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" runat="server"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" )%>" />



     <link href="~/Content/MasterStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" runat="server" />



    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <%--  [if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]--%>
</head>
<body>
```

Products.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="Products" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Products.aspx.cs" Inherits="ShopSystem.Products.Products" %>

  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
     <style type="text/css">
    .ZeroQuantity {
        background-color :rgba(255, 87, 34, 0.41);
    }      

    .LowQuantity {
        background-color :  rgba(255, 152, 0, 0.41);
    }
</style> 
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div class="ProductPage">
        <h1 class="Pagetitle">Products Table</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 navbar-right">
```

Comment: Please post Products.aspx, and Master page if you have one.

Comment: what's you mean by post products.aspx?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: there is a much code in Prodcuts.aspx and master page, can i upload the pages for you in media fire ?

Comment: Please show the minimum viable codes. We do not need/want to see the entire page.

Comment: done , that is fine ?

Comment: It seems that Products.aspx is not using correct master page. Could you double check it?

Comment: i have edited the code of master page .. First one was not corrent

Comment: Products Page works fine when i make it on the root directly
http://ammm199462-001-site1.gtempurl.com/Products.aspx